# How do you implement AsynSelect with isMilti in Typescript? #react-select

Tags: react-select

I can't seem to get isMulti to work with Aysync select. I've tried a number of iterations but nothing works. Below is my code. Once I uncomment the isMulti line, thats whne things break. I tried to create a new array type to see if that helps but it doesn't.

I also have another issue where the options box doesn't load the options from the promise function but only does so when I delete a character from the input (it's using the cached results to populated the dropdown at that point).

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import ValueType from 'react-select';
import { getGoogleAutoComplete } from './services';
import map from '../../assets/map.svg';
import './LocationInput.styles.scss';


type OptionType = {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}

type OptionTypeArray = Array<OptionType>;


const LocationInput: FunctionComponent = () => {


    const [locations, setLocations] = useState<ValueType<OptionType | OptionTypeArray>>();

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (option: ValueType<OptionType | OptionTypeArray> | null) => {
        if (option != null){setLocations(option)};
        console.log('im in handleChange!')
        console.log(option)
      };

      async function promiseOptions(): Promise<any>{

        return await getGoogleAutoComplete(query);

      }


        return (

            <div className='location-input-container'>
                <div className='map-icon'>
                    <img src={map} alt=''/>
                </div>
                <div className='location-input'>
                    <AsyncSelect
                        //isMulti={true}
                        cacheOptions
                        value={locations}
                        defaultOptions
                        placeholder='Enter a City or ZIP code'
                        onChange={(option) => handleChange(option)}
                        onInputChange={(value) => setQuery(value)}
                        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                        noOptionsMessage={() => 'No Match Found'}
                        isClearable={true}
                        loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}

export default LocationInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. However, I had to use Type Assertion to make it workout which isn't the ideal approach. If anyone has any other suggestions I'd greaty appreacite it.

```
import { useState, FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import { getGoogleAutoComplete } from './services';
import OptionTypeBase from 'react-select';
import { OptionsType } from 'react-select/src/types';
import makeAnimated from "react-select/animated";
import map from '../../assets/map.svg';
import './LocationInput.styles.scss';




const LocationInput: FunctionComponent = () => {


    const [locations, setLocations] = useState<OptionsType<OptionTypeBase>>();

    const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (option: OptionsType<OptionTypeBase>) => {
        setLocations(option);
        console.log('im in handleChange!')
        console.log(option)
      };

      async function promiseOptions(value:string): Promise<any>{

        return new Promise(resolve => resolve(getGoogleAutoComplete(value)));

      }

        //get animated components wrapper
        const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();


        return (

            <div className='location-input-container'>
                <div className='map-icon'>
                    <img src={map} alt=''/>
                </div>
                <div className='location-input'>
                    <AsyncSelect
                        isMulti={true}
                        components={animatedComponents}
                        cacheOptions
                        placeholder='Enter a City or ZIP code'
                        onChange={(option) => handleChange(option as OptionsType<OptionTypeBase>)}
                        closeMenuOnSelect={true}
                        noOptionsMessage={() => 'No Match Found'}
                        loadOptions={promiseOptions} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}

export default LocationInput;
```